# how to scrape all <li> instances under a specific div and process it

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML: I want to loop for the data in between the li values, specifically I want to get the id so in the first item I want to get  **id="product-38350"** and the size it corresponds to **EU 36** I then want to add it to a son. I can handle that part but I'm struggling with getting the actual data on looping.

```
<form class="product-form js-product-form " action="/en/cart/add" method="post">
   <fieldset class="product-form__section">
      <legend class="product-form__section-title">Choose size</legend>
      <ul class="product-sizes">
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38350" value="38350" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38350" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 36
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38351" value="38351" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38351" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 36.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38352" value="38352" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38352" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 37
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38353" value="38353" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38353" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 37.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38354" value="38354" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38354" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 38
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38355" value="38355" class="product-sizes__input" disabled="">
            <label for="product-38355" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 38.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38356" value="38356" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38356" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 39
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38357" value="38357" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38357" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 39.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38358" value="38358" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38358" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 40
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38359" value="38359" class="product-sizes__input" disabled="">
            <label for="product-38359" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 40.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38360" value="38360" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38360" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 41
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38361" value="38361" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38361" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 41.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38362" value="38362" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38362" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 42
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38363" value="38363" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38363" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 42.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38364" value="38364" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38364" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 43
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38365" value="38365" class="product-sizes__input" disabled="">
            <label for="product-38365" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 43.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38366" value="38366" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38366" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 44
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38367" value="38367" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38367" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 44.5
            </label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38368" value="38368" class="product-sizes__input">
            <label for="product-38368" class="product-sizes__label">
            EU 45
            </label>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </fieldset>
   <div class="product-form__actions">
      <button class="product-form__btn btn" type="submit" autocomplete="off" data-select="Select size" disabled="">
      <span>Add to cart</span>
      </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

I have tried loads of things in b4s and regex but it just returns an empty list []. Here is some code I have tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<form class="product-form js-product-form" action="/en/cart/add" method="post"><fieldset class="product-form__section"><legend class="product-form__section-title">Choose size</legend><ul class="product-sizes"><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38350" value="38350" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38350" class="product-sizes__label">EU 36</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38351" value="38351" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38351" class="product-sizes__label">EU 36.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38352" value="38352" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38352" class="product-sizes__label">EU 37</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38353" value="38353" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38353" class="product-sizes__label">EU 37.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38354" value="38354" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38354" class="product-sizes__label">EU 38</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38355" value="38355" class="product-sizes__input" disabled><label for="product-38355" class="product-sizes__label">EU 38.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38356" value="38356" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38356" class="product-sizes__label">EU 39</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38357" value="38357" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38357" class="product-sizes__label">EU 39.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38358" value="38358" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38358" class="product-sizes__label">EU 40</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38359" value="38359" class="product-sizes__input" disabled><label for="product-38359" class="product-sizes__label">EU 40.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38360" value="38360" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38360" class="product-sizes__label">EU 41</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38361" value="38361" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38361" class="product-sizes__label">EU 41.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38362" value="38362" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38362" class="product-sizes__label">EU 42</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38363" value="38363" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38363" class="product-sizes__label">EU 42.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38364" value="38364" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38364" class="product-sizes__label">EU 43</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38365" value="38365" class="product-sizes__input" disabled><label for="product-38365" class="product-sizes__label">EU 43.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38366" value="38366" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38366" class="product-sizes__label">EU 44</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38367" value="38367" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38367" class="product-sizes__label">EU 44.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38368" value="38368" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38368" class="product-sizes__label">EU 45</label></li></ul></fieldset><div class="product-form__actions"><button class="product-form__btn btn" type="submit" autocomplete="off" data-select="Select size" disabled><span>Add to cart</span></button></div></form>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find_all('form', class_="product-list js-product-list")
print(div)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use access the "id" by accessing the tags attributes using the `[]` notation, and access the "Size" using the `find_next()` method.

```
...
fmt_string = "{:<20} {:<20}"
print(fmt_string.format("ID", "Size"))
print("-" * 30)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select(".product-form__section input"):
    print(
        fmt_string.format(
            tag["id"], tag.find_next('label').get_text(strip=True)
            )
            )
```

Output:

```
ID                   Size                
------------------------------
product-38350        EU 36               
product-38351        EU 36.5             
product-38352        EU 37               
product-38353        EU 37.5             
product-38354        EU 38               
product-38355        EU 38.5             
product-38356        EU 39               
product-38357        EU 39.5             
product-38358        EU 40               
product-38359        EU 40.5             
product-38360        EU 41               
product-38361        EU 41.5             
product-38362        EU 42               
product-38363        EU 42.5             
product-38364        EU 43               
product-38365        EU 43.5             
product-38366        EU 44               
product-38367        EU 44.5             
product-38368        EU 45
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the exact class attribute in there:

Should be `product-form js-product-form`, not `product-list js-product-list`

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<form class="product-form js-product-form" action="/en/cart/add" method="post"><fieldset class="product-form__section"><legend class="product-form__section-title">Choose size</legend><ul class="product-sizes"><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38350" value="38350" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38350" class="product-sizes__label">EU 36</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38351" value="38351" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38351" class="product-sizes__label">EU 36.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38352" value="38352" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38352" class="product-sizes__label">EU 37</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38353" value="38353" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38353" class="product-sizes__label">EU 37.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38354" value="38354" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38354" class="product-sizes__label">EU 38</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38355" value="38355" class="product-sizes__input" disabled><label for="product-38355" class="product-sizes__label">EU 38.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38356" value="38356" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38356" class="product-sizes__label">EU 39</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38357" value="38357" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38357" class="product-sizes__label">EU 39.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38358" value="38358" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38358" class="product-sizes__label">EU 40</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38359" value="38359" class="product-sizes__input" disabled><label for="product-38359" class="product-sizes__label">EU 40.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38360" value="38360" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38360" class="product-sizes__label">EU 41</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38361" value="38361" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38361" class="product-sizes__label">EU 41.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38362" value="38362" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38362" class="product-sizes__label">EU 42</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38363" value="38363" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38363" class="product-sizes__label">EU 42.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38364" value="38364" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38364" class="product-sizes__label">EU 43</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38365" value="38365" class="product-sizes__input" disabled><label for="product-38365" class="product-sizes__label">EU 43.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38366" value="38366" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38366" class="product-sizes__label">EU 44</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38367" value="38367" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38367" class="product-sizes__label">EU 44.5</label></li><li><input type="radio" name="id" id="product-38368" value="38368" class="product-sizes__input"><label for="product-38368" class="product-sizes__label">EU 45</label></li></ul></fieldset><div class="product-form__actions"><button class="product-form__btn btn" type="submit" autocomplete="off" data-select="Select size" disabled><span>Add to cart</span></button></div></form>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find_all('form', class_="product-form js-product-form")
print(div)
```

**Output:**

```
print(div)
[<form action="/en/cart/add" class="product-form js-product-form" method="post"><fieldset class="product-form__section"><legend class="product-form__section-title">Choose size</legend><ul class="product-sizes"><li><input class="product-sizes__input" id="product-38350" name="id" type="radio" value="38350"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38350">EU 36</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" id="product-38351" name="id" type="radio" value="38351"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38351">EU 36.5</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" id="product-38352" name="id" type="radio" value="38352"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38352">EU 37</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" id="product-38353" name="id" type="radio" value="38353"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38353">EU 37.5</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" id="product-38354" name="id" type="radio" value="38354"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38354">EU 38</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" disabled="" id="product-38355" name="id" type="radio" value="38355"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38355">EU 38.5</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" id="product-38356" name="id" type="radio" value="38356"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38356">EU 39</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" id="product-38357" name="id" type="radio" value="38357"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38357">EU 39.5</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" id="product-38358" name="id" type="radio" value="38358"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38358">EU 40</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" disabled="" id="product-38359" name="id" type="radio" value="38359"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38359">EU 40.5</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" id="product-38360" name="id" type="radio" value="38360"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38360">EU 41</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" id="product-38361" name="id" type="radio" value="38361"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38361">EU 41.5</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" id="product-38362" name="id" type="radio" value="38362"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38362">EU 42</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" id="product-38363" name="id" type="radio" value="38363"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38363">EU 42.5</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" id="product-38364" name="id" type="radio" value="38364"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38364">EU 43</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" disabled="" id="product-38365" name="id" type="radio" value="38365"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38365">EU 43.5</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" id="product-38366" name="id" type="radio" value="38366"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38366">EU 44</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" id="product-38367" name="id" type="radio" value="38367"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38367">EU 44.5</label></li><li><input class="product-sizes__input" id="product-38368" name="id" type="radio" value="38368"/><label class="product-sizes__label" for="product-38368">EU 45</label></li></ul></fieldset><div class="product-form__actions"><button autocomplete="off" class="product-form__btn btn" data-select="Select size" disabled="" type="submit"><span>Add to cart</span></button></div></form>]
```